# TextView wrap causes adjacent ImageView to disappear

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-linearlayout

I'm puzzled by a simple-looking issue I can't figure out. Got a display button that includes an image (flag), a text, and another image (caret). These three are in a layout container, which is assigned a weight since there's another button next to it. Here's how the layout container looks:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/countryselect"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight=".88"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:clickable="true" 
     android:onClick="clickHandler" >
       <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/countryflag"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:paddingRight="8dp"        
         android:src="@drawable/flag_argentina" />
       <TextView
         android:id="@+id/countryname"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="@string/app_title"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textColor="#4898c0" />
       <ImageView
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="4dp"
         android:src="@drawable/corner" />
   </LinearLayout>
```

The whole thing works fine if the text in the TextView fits in one line. If it doesn't, ie, if the text wraps to two lines, the caret image completely disappears (while the flag displays vertically centered as it should). Flag image and caret have the same pixel height.  Note that the other button (not shown in the above code) that's to the right of this LinearLayout still displays fine, so the issue is not that the caret image is pushed off the right side of the screen.

Any idea why this may be happening/what I can do to keep the caret image visible?  Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

as the text extends it make the 2md image out of the screen so fix the width of the TextView using wieght some

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/countryselect"
     android:orientation="horizontal"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_weight=".88"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:clickable="true" 
     android:onClick="clickHandler" 
     android:weightSum="1">
       <ImageView
         android:id="@+id/countryflag"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:paddingRight="8dp"        
         android:src="@drawable/launcher_icon"
         android:layout_weight=".3" />
       <TextView
         android:id="@+id/countryname"
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:text="@string/app_title"
         android:textStyle="bold"
         android:textColor="#4898c0" 
          android:layout_weight=".4"/>
       <ImageView
         android:layout_width="0dp"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent"
         android:paddingLeft="4dp"
         android:src="@drawable/launcher_icon" 
          android:layout_weight=".3"/>
   </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi Dheeresh, Appreciate your thought but I think that's not the issue I have. The other button (not shown in the above code) that's to the right of this LinearLayout still displays fine, so the issue is not that the caret image is pushed off the right side of the screen. In other words, the caret image disappears but the one in a different LinearLayout to the right of it displays just fine. Hope this clarifies it.